# returning a list from a mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

When I look in my `DetailsReport(List<> filteredList)` method, it's Count = 0. Is it possible to send a `List` to your controller or is my code bad?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Print Results to Report",
                 "DetailsReport",
                 new {filteredList = Model} )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is bad. You can't pass a Model as part of the Route like that. You need to serialize your Model and send it as either part of the request payload or in the query string. Try something like this (not sure if my serialization is correct with the Razor syntax as I haven't used it):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Print Results to Report", "DetailsReport", null, new {@id = "printreport")

$(function() {
   $('#printreport').click(function() {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).wrap('<form action="' + $(this).attr('href') + '?' + 
             $.param(@new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model)) + 
             '" style="display: inline" method="GET" />');
      $(this).parent('form').submit();
   });
});
```